# jquery multiselect keep the value from previous onChange events doesn't update using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, multi-select

I have used jquery multiselect and display data fetched from database using AJAX.

Multiselect dropdown occurs when I change the drop down suppose division so I need all the student list in multiselect. It will work fine only once but when we again change it, it will show the previous fetched value not the new ones.

But problem occurs when we again change the value of dropdown(calling AJAX ) the multiselect dropdown value can't be changed.

```
<select class="form-control col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="student" name="studentParentNo" multiple="multiple">
                                </select>     
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#div").change(function(){
                 var value = $(this).val();
                 $.get("StudentSMS.jsp",{q:value},function(data){
                  $("#student").html(data);
                  $('#student').show();
                 $(function () {
                        $('#student').multiselect({
                            includeSelectAllOption: true
                        });
                    });

                 });
             });
         });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Guys I try this its working for me

jquery .load() i have reload particular "div" from id and its work fine

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="test">
<select class="form-control col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="student"
                name="studentParentNo" multiple="multiple">
    </select>

<script>
$("#div").change(function(){
   //this will load the "select" option  
   $("#test").load(location.href+ " #student"); 
       var value1 = $('#class').val();
       var value = $(this).val();

$.get("StudentSMS.jsp",{q:value,p:value1},function(data){
      $("#student").html(data);
      $('#student').show();
                  $(function () {
                        $('#student').multiselect({
                                 includeSelectAllOption: true
          });
                  });
                        });
                            });

 </script>
</div>
```